# How to give a rust program access (permission) to my camera?

Tags: rust, webcam, uvc

I'm using `uvc` to try and get frames from my webcam. Everything is working up to the point where I try and open the webcam device.

Code:

```rust
use uvc::{Context, Frame};

fn main() {
    let ctx = Context::new().expect("Could not create context");
    let dev = ctx
        .find_device(None, None, None)
        .expect("Could not find device");

    let devh = dev.open().expect("Could not open device");
}
```

Error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not open device: Access'

This is all just part of an example in the Uvc github, really I don't have any clues of what's going on. I'm using Ubuntu 22.10.

I've tried using `sudo cargo run` instead, but rust isn't installed for root user, so it didn't work. I'd also prefer to avoid sudo if possible.

Comment: `cargo run` is there for convenience, but you don't actually need `sudo` to build your code. You can use `cargo build` then call `sudo target/my_crate_name` if `sudo` is required for running your application. However, that assumes the problem requires `sudo` in the first place. It may just be another issue related to finding the device.

Comment: My computer has a little physical switch on the side that disables camera access and can't be toggled from software. While I'm very happy it's there, I also routinely forget it and get confused when my computer randomly can't find my camera. Is it possible that your device has a similar security measure that you've forgotten to toggle?

Answer (score -1):

have u tried to change the access on usb device?
You can find the answer in the uav doc itself.
https://crates.io/crates/uvc